# Thorntail (wldfly swarm) logging to Greylog

Tags: logging, graylog2, wildfly-swarm, gelf

How can I enable wildfly swarm logging to greylog - or put in other words: do logging in gelf format? Has anyone done this already?

It seems there are only framworkes on the graylog marketplace that work together with log4j ([gelfj](https://marketplace.graylog.org/addons/a3c8bbdf-6b47-43fe-8298-f259db85fc59)) or logback but not with the jboss logging system. And from other questions on SO I assume that it's not possible to configure thorntail to log with log4j (which would feel somewhat wrong anyway: pipe logging through jboss logging in to log4j to funnel it into gelf ..)

The underlying requirement is that I want to docker my swarm application and use greylog as centralized logging. I understand that I can configure docker to log into gelf but that would mean I do not have control over the extended gelf functions in my application, right?

What would be the preferred way to achieve centralized logging from thorntail/swarm?

Comment: I've used either Logstash or FluentD in the past as a centralized logging mechanism

Comment: Unfortunately I am tied to graylog for this project :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to send logs to graylog in thorntail, because some has implemented a jboss compatible gelf log handler for us. Some restrictions would be which logging framework you use. I had to use the jboss logger via slf4j and did not spend more time to get log4j running. Maybe you find out how this can be achieved.

### Where do I get a jboss compatible log handler for gelf?

Here you find the git repository of the jboss compatible log handler which supports gelf format.

https://github.com/mp911de/logstash-gelf

### How do I configure the log handler?

See the following link for the doc of this log handler.

https://logging.paluch.biz/

### How do I integrate it in thorntail?

For that you have to do some work.

#### 1. Add the dependcy to your pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>biz.paluch.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>logstash-gelf</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

#### 2. Create a custom module.xml for thorntail

src/main/resources/modules/biz/paluch/logging/main/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="biz.paluch.logging">
    <resources>
        <artifact name="biz.paluch.logging:logstash-gelf:1.11.2" />
        <artifact name="redis.clients:jedis:2.9.0" />
        <artifact name="org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:2.4.3" />
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        <module name="org.slf4j" />
        <module name="javax.api" />
        <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

#### 3. Configure thorntail to use this log handler

```
swarm:
  jaeger:
  logging:
    file-handlers:
    custom-handlers:
      GELF-HTTP:
        named-formatter: MY_LOG_PATTERN
        attribute-class: biz.paluch.logging.gelf.wildfly.WildFlyGelfLogHandler
        module: biz.paluch.logging
        properties:
          host: "http://graylog"
          extractStackTrace: true
          includeFullMdc: true
          maximumMessageSize: 1048576
    root-logger:
      level: WARN
      handlers:
        - CONSOLE
        - GELF-HTTP
```

#### How to make the logger available in my application?

```
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Default;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;

/**
 * This produces and configures the logger.
 *
 * @author Thomas Herzog <herzog.thomas81@gmail.com>
 * @since 06/08/18
 */
@ApplicationScoped
public class LoggerConfiguration {

    @Produces
    @Default
    @Dependent
    Logger createLogger(final InjectionPoint ip) {
        if (ip.getBean() != null) {
            return Logger.getLogger(ip.getBean().getBeanClass());
        } else if (ip.getMember() != null) {
            return Logger.getLogger(ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass());
        } else {
            return Logger.getLogger("default");
        }
    }
}
```